# 301 htaccess redirect dynamic URL in a subfolder to home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched for this and am unable to find and answer. 
I am trying to use htaccess to 301 redirect URL:
http://example.com/en/option=com_content&view=article&id=86:estate-gates&catid=91:estate-gates&Itemid=480
to the home page at example.com

I have in my htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} en/option=com_content&view=article&id=86:estate-gates&catid=91:estate-gates&Itemid=480 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/? [L,R=302]

I believe the subfolder 'en/' in the RewriteCond is where my problem is although I can't seem to be able to solve it.

Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated

Comment: I doubt the URL you posted is correct, actually it is invalid... I could imagine the correct URL is `http://example.com/en?option=com_content&...` ?

Comment: Kind thanks arkascha - I will check it again to be sure. The site has been moved & changed from joomla to just an html site so I'm not surprised the URL does not exist anymore.

Comment: This is not about "existing", but simply about what characters are allowed in a URL and what makes sense from a semantic point of view...

Comment: Yes agree, Thank You